# Adjust scrollbar button position through CSS only

Tags: html, css

[image]

Is it possible to move the scroll bar button(as highlighted in the image) little below its actual position?
My understanding is that the top value for the button is same as the top value of the div. Basically, I need the total scrollbar to be placed exactly in the center of the div.

The below code has no effect on the button's position:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
     top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the scrollbars for the viewport is a matter for the browser, and can't be controlled with HTML/CSS.

Your best bet would be to add a thick border around the box of same background color as that of the box, and reducing width/height accordingly.

Or even hide scrollbar-button like:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4nuoo8vg/

Comment: Adding a border helped. Thanks a lot!