# How to keep a scrollbar always bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scroll-bar in a div element and initially it's position is top. Whenever i add some text to the div element then the scroll-bar does not move. Is there any way, the scroll-bar of the div element's position will be always bottom and whenever I add some text to the div element, the scroll-bar also goes to the bottom automatically?

Here's my div element:

```
<div class='panel-Body scroll' id='messageBody'></div>
```

And CSS class

```
.scroll {
            height: 450px;
            overflow: scroll;  
        }
```

What i need is, initially the position of the scroll-bar should be bottom.

Also when i clicked a send message, I'm adding the message to the div elements 'messageBody'. On that time the the scroll-bar should be down again.

This is the current style of my scroll-bar
[image]

And I want it to be always
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust scrollbar button position through CSS only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516271/adjust-scrollbar-button-position-through-css-only)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
var messageBody = document.querySelector('#messageBody');
messageBody.scrollTop = messageBody.scrollHeight - messageBody.clientHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Janet Wu It's working. I'll remember you.

Comment: native js great ;)

Comment: ever heard about the `[element].scrollIntoView();` command?

Answer (score 8):

Something like this should do what you want if I understood what you want correctly.

Replace `messageBody` in `getElementById()` with your chat message container id.

```
var chatHistory = document.getElementById("messageBody");
chatHistory.scrollTop = chatHistory.scrollHeight;
```

This will scroll the message container to the bottom.
Since scroll position is recorded in pixel and not percentage, the scroll position doesn't change as you add more elements into the container by default.

Do this after you have appended a new message into your chat message container.

Comment: I don't know, it's not working, somehow i may missed something. Did you taka a look to may source code?

Comment: @BMShamsNahid I don't see source code of your Javascript anywhere. Only HTML and CSS.

Comment: i upvote it ... seems the person who ask the question doesn't know what he's trying to do

Comment: great explanation there @josephting

Comment: That the right answer. Cause Janet Wu version is scroll up if you scrolled up before make changes.

Comment: this seems to be working in Chrome but not in Firefox. Can someone help ?

Comment: @Ramya It works for me on both Chrome and Firefox though. https://codepen.io/josephting/pen/XWdGrME

Comment: @josephting yes.. it is working for both Chrome and Firefox. It didn't work initially because of the 'flex-direction: column-reverse' issue in Firefox. I upvote the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Assume your html code like this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="parentDiv">
  <div class="people">1</div>
  <div class="people">2</div>
  <div class="people">3</div>
  <div class="people">4</div>
  <div class="people">5</div>
  <div class="people">6</div>
  <div class="people">7</div>
  <div class="people">8</div>
  <div class="people">9</div>
</div>
```

And then wrap your js like this

**JS**

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("parentDiv");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lf8fkhzk/)

Answer (score 5):

That'd be :: **`messageBody.lastChild.scrollIntoView();`** //for the initial scroll to bottom position.

---

p.s.: After the page load, this command should be called by your message handler on message update.

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer.

Comment: Warning: Doesn't seem to always work.

Comment: `lastElementChild` seems to work better. The nice thing about using `scrollIntoView()` is that you can do customizations on the scrolling, like `scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })`, for smooth scrolling. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score 4):

Here you go. Follow this concept.

```js
$('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight);
```

```css
#chatbox-history {
  overflow: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#messages {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
}
#messages div {
  border: 1px solid #e2e4e3;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chatbox-history">
  <div id="messages">
    <div>asdjf ;asd</div>
    <div>ajsd fa ;skd f;s</div>
    <div>asdjf ;akjs d;lf a;lksd fj</div>
    <div>ajsd fkaj s;dlf a;ljsdl;fkja;lsd f; asd</div>
    <div>Wassup?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice answer there you got mate ;)

Answer (score -1):

It's already **2023** and you can simply use `Element.scrollIntoView()` now! Check MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

```js
var messageBody = document.querySelector('#messageBody');
messageBody.scrollIntoView();
```

——-

**11 June Updated**

For those who downvote this answer, plz make sure you have an element fixed in the bottom of a scroll area as the target, and call this function every time the content updated. Besides, please check the MDN doc and ensure your browser meet the requirement!

Comment: sounds good, doesn't work

Comment: @asdfgh It works actually for me. You should have an element (it’s the messagebody in my answer) actually in the bottom of the area, and call this method every time the content updated.

Comment: This works nice when having an element in the bottom of the page that can be referenced and scroll into.