# How to set scrollbar at the bottom by default?

Tags: reactjs

I have template message in image.

Can you help me set scrollbar at the bottom by default?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: What do you mean, extend the scrollbar all the way to the bottom? Or have it scrolled to the bottom to start with?

Comment: This is already answered in the thread. Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903462/how-to-keep-a-scrollbar-always-bottom

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript code below should keep your div's scrollbar positioned at the bottom like you described:

```
let objDiv = document.getElementById("divExample");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

link below: [Link here](http://web.archive.org/web/20080821211053/http://radio.javaranch.com/pascarello/2005/12/14/1134573598403.html)

Comment: Adding some explanation would make this answer more useful.

Comment: i have updated my answer please check and let me know if anything

Answer (score 0):

Use [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) on the element you wish to display at the bottom. For example, for the last message of a chat you want to show :

elementMessage.scrollIntoView(true);

It will make the parent element scroll until your element is visible (here with the optional parameter alignToTop set to true, the element will be aligned at the top of the scrollable parent, or as high as possible if it's your last element).