# How to scroll to latest message when have new message with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm implementing a chat app, but I can't handle for scroll to bottom when have new message.
I have tried both:

```
document.getElementById('msg_history').scrollTop = document.getElementById('msg_history').scrollHeight
```

and

```
this.$refs.msg_history.scrollTop = this.$refs.msg_history.scrollHeight
```

But it still not work, scrollTop value is not change.

Here my code:
https://codepen.io/c7n/pen/xxKroNY

Thanks,
Chung Tran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cover your code with nextTick(() => {})
like this:

```
  this.$nextTick(() => {
     document.getElementsByClassName('msg_history')[0].scrollTop = some value;                      
  })
```

This will wait till all rendering has done.
And checkout the way of calc the top location below:

[How to keep a scrollbar always bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903462/how-to-keep-a-scrollbar-always-bottom)