# How to set the vertical scroll handler at the bottom on page load

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a div with an overflow hidden property, and I want the scroll position to be at the bottom when my page loads.

I have this :

[image: 1]

I want this when I load my page :

[image: 2]

Any idea ?

Comment: Can You More Describe Your Problem.Or you only want to scroll the div to end as page loads.

Comment: that's it, I just want my users to see the last message when they arrive on the page

Comment: Are we allowed to use jquery?

Comment: Yes sure, if you know how to do it with jquery

Comment: You need to use javascript, please do some research, make an attempt and if you get stuck, come back and post a question about what you are stuck with.  In it's current form, your question is too broad and therefore off topic for SO

Comment: @Petoux you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903462/how-to-keep-a-scrollbar-always-bottom

Comment: but he dont want to make scrollbar on bottom forever.

Comment: I'm looking for javascript way to do it, @ManojKadolkar it's not working

Comment: @Petoux please consider a green tick if my answer helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Can Be Easily Done By This Method....

```js
function setItem(){
    // We go through all items and change the value of the id attribute to empty
    $('#mylist li').each(function (i, v) {
       $(v).attr('id', '');
    });

    // We add the items
    $('#mylist').append('<li id="last">test</li>');

    // Currently there is only one identifier called "last"
    window.location.href = '#last';
}
```

```css
#mylist{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="setItem();">Add</button>
<div id="mylist"></div>
```

Just create new li and modify it's id to last and hrefing the document to last.
Then remove id attribute from all li.
Here li are messages.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look into JS method [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: No this can't be achieved using scrollIntoView because we not have track to last message.And on another hand we can use it.